# Kubernetes docker private registry with TLS and without username

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I create a private Docker registry without username and password, only with TLS.

```
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://<my-domain>/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Warning  Failed     14m (x4 over 16m)    kubelet, ip-172-10-10-157  Error: ErrImagePull
```

I tried with

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry docker-registry-dev --docker-server=<my-domain>
```

And I get this error:

```
required flag(s) "docker-password", "docker-username" not set
```

From the command line with docker I can pull correct my docker image.

Any ideas for Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

This really should work out of the box without `imagePullSecrets` and considering your registry has valid and signed certs. It looks more like your node cannot connect to `https://<my-domain>/v2/`.  A couple of things you can check:

1. Your registry's [http](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#http) section is configured to listen on https on the right port.
2. Check with something like `curl https://registry-name/v2/` from one of your Kubernetes nodes and that you have connectivity.

Comment: I add username and password but i get this error in kubernetes:

rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://my-domain:443/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Comment: what did you use to deploy the cluster?